# Filter subprojects from Main SVN Repository

Tags: svn

We have one main repository but we want to split these into different repositorys.

The problem is we have a bunch of sub-projects that start with the same name for example:

```
\navigator
\navigator workbench
\navigator example
```

I'm using the command:

```
svndumpfilter include navigator --drop-empty-revs < svn-sump > navigator.dump
```

And we keep getting a error message halfway through, is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 1):

Reorganize your sub-projects in a different directory structure.

```
/navigator/main
/navigator/workbench
/navigator/example
```